# RowMapper put multiple results into list attribute

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I want to run a JDBC query (on SQL Server) in Spring which will (loosely) get me the following table:

```
+-----------------+
| ID Text Country |
+-----------------+
| 1  Test US      |
| 1  Test UK      |
+-----------------+
```

I want to put this in a Java class like this:

```
class TestClass {
    private int id;
    private String text;
    private List<String> country;
}
```

So, the above should give me only one object. Can I/how can I do this with the RowMapper? If I have

```
public TestClass mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    TestClass test = new TestClass();
    test.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
    test.setText(rs.getString("Text"));
    return test;
}
```

I cannot really aggregate multiple rows, because RowMapper (as the name suggests) works on rows.

I did this with Hibernate before, which works, but is terribly slow, so I would like to generate all needed results on the SQL Server as soon as possible. Because I only need the result for creating a JSON object, I guess it is ok if I work on String basis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ResultSetExtractor instead of RowMapper.

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor;

public class DBReader implements ResultSetExtractor {

@Override
public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
        DataAccessException {

    Map<String, TestClass> items = new HashMap<String, TestClass>();

    while(rs.next()) {

        TestClass test = items.get(rs.getString("ID"));

        if (test == null) {

            test = new TestClass();
            test.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
            test.setText(rs.getString("Text"));

        } 

        test.getCountry().add(rs.getString("Country"));
    }

    return items;
}

}
```

In your TestClass, change you country list holder like below

```
    private List<String> country = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to insert `while (rs.next()){}` and `items.put(rs.getString("ID"), test);`. Additionally I used a TreeMap (although I still have to do think a little bit about the sorting) and afterwards had to convert it to a ArrayList by `new ArrayList<TestClass>(items.values());`

Comment: I missed the while loop part, thank you for informing me, Updated the same in my response.